# Unable to shrink a partition in osx 10.10

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

[image]

Hi, I installed windows using bootcamp, but i made the mistake to make the bootcamp only 20gb, so i want to expand it. I found a way to do so, but firstly i need to shrink my other partition - Macintosh HD, why am I unable to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have another solution; hope it would work fine. Backup Windows data (bootcamp) firstly. Use Bootcamp utility to delete the existing Windows partition. Once you delete it, recreate new Windows partition with Bootcamp a little larger as you desire. Then reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious reason is your primary partition is full. Can't shrink a partition to smaller than it's contents, and you will need some extra space for rearrangement.

Empty the trash (Finder, Mail, iPhoto etc), delete apps you don't need, delete downloads you no longer need etc.

You may still have problems resizing the partition as a full partition leaves things in odd places. Free space and useful space are not always the same thing.

Best way is get a large external drive (cheap these days), copy your internal drive to it, erase the internal, partition it as you wish, copy back. In some cases this process is faster than resizing a partition as files have to be copied only twice, not moved around like Tetris blocks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have two external hard drives  and most of my information is there. I have deleted almost everything i don't need, and i managed to free only 60gb,so i wanted to shrink the Macintosh HD with 50, and then add these 50 to bootcamp. But you are saying that i need to empty more memory. I will try, thanks!

Comment: Even shring Macintosh HD, you can not extend Bootcamp partition without losing data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by turning off filevault.  Then, letting osx decrypt the hard drive.  After a reboot, I was able to resize my partition.